# How to match this line by regular expression in MATLAB?

Tags: regex, matlab

Here is the line I try to match:

```
976 | 9760000 | 9769999 | Blabon | List
```

It is simply on a multi line string inside Matlab variable. I try to match this line. How can I do it in Matlab ?

Comment: we need a *bit* more context to give you a good answer. Like, should the numbers always be the same length? is the spacing important? Should the strings at the end always be the same? Are they what you want as output, or the entire string, or the numbers, or...? What does the rest of your data look like? ...etc. Just know, that we don't know what you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
\d{3}\s+\|(\s+\d{7}\s+\|){2}\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+\|\s+[a-zA-Z]+
```